# Add items to browser context menu?

Tags: browser, contextmenu

I have a page in which an augmented context menu would be natural and intuitive for a visitor. Not so different from a ton of pages, I'm sure. **EDIT:** Of course, I must do that without losing any of the browser's native context-menu items/actions. Just want to add an item.

Is there any way to accomplish that yet in any browser?

We can imagine (putative) markup for such a thing. Maybe somehting like:

<context n onclick="handleNewItem"> my new item </context>

where *n* is the line number of "my new item"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could totally replace the context menu with your own, but then you'd loose the standard browser's one.

Unless you are writing a browser extension, I don't know of any way to just append commands to the browser's context menu from within javascript.